# Macro Excel second worksheet value copied by first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in same Excel.

First excel sheet contains the following fields

```
 No       Material           10th july  11th july
  1   DATUM DCP ESD Black                    
  2   DATUM DCP ESD Blue
```

My second worksheet contains the following fields

```
No     Date             Material            Stock size+Wastage
  1  10th july      DATUM DCP ESD Black          283.47 
  2  10th july      DATUM DCP ESD Black          661.6
  3  11th july      DATUM DCP ESD Blue           665.6  
  4  11th july      DATUM DCP ESD Black           50.8
```

I want the following Expected result in the first worksheet:-

```
 No      Material             10th july  11th july
  1   DATUM DCP ESD Black      945.07    50.8         
  2   DATUM DCP ESD Blue                 665.6
```

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please show the code you already have tried and ask a *specific* question to it (you even didn't ask a question yet). Read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: This should be pretty simple to write. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: actually, i don't know in macro code and there basics that only I ask to help

Answer (score 3):

Forget the macro, just use a pivot table.
You can always refresh a pivot table after adding more data to the set it pulling from.

This is how the pivot table would look like:
[image: pic of pivot table of the data]

How I set up the fields in the pivot table:
[image: how i set up the fields in the pivot table]

Comment: okay thank you:) i ll do it

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA here. Ignore the first sheet and create a pivot table from the second sheet.

Comment: pivot table ? i dont use pivot table in before okay i ll check on this

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub summ()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & "65536").End(xlUp).row).Name = "Dates"
        .Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & "65536").End(xlUp).row).Name = "Materials"
        .Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & "65536").End(xlUp).row).Name = "Numbers"
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(2, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=SUMPRODUCT( (Worksheets("Sheet2")!Dates=R1C) * (Worksheets("Sheet2")!Materials=RC1) * (Worksheets("Sheet2")!Numbers)"
        .Range(Cells(2, 3).Address).AutoFill _
            Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 3).Address, Cells(2, Y)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range(Cells(2, X).Address).AutoFill _
            Destination:=Range(Cells(2, Y).Address, Cells(X, Y)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Where "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are names of first and second sheet respectively.
Where X is last used row (number_of_materials - 1).
Where Y is last used column (number_of_dates - 1).
Since it isn't complex task I would recommend using formulas, not a macro.